# Regarding a geometrical proof of irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ based on $\gcd$.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

In the below image stated on article's page 17, on $\gcd$ there is proof for irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ [here](http://stepanovpapers.com/gcd.pdf).[image: here] Have some questions:
1. I am unable to understand how it is deduced geometrically that $|EB| = |EF|$.
 2. How it is deduced that $\gcd(AC,AB)=\gcd(CE,CF).$
 3. How it is deduced that $|EC|\gt |EB|$, or is it just an hypothesis/assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's assumed $AB=AF$. Since angles at $B$ and $F$ are also equal and the the triangles $ABE$ and $AFE$ share the $EF$ length, their third sides are equal, too, by Pythagorean theorem. Hence the two triangles are congruent.
2. $AC=AF+CF=AB+CF$  – and if a sum ($AC$) shares a divisor with one addend ($AB$) then it must share the same divisor with another one ($CF$).
   On the other hand $AB=CB=CE+BE=CE+CF$, so similarly the common divisor of a sum and one addend must be a divisor of another addend, so $\gcd(AB,CF)=\gcd(CE,CF).$
   Hence $\gcd(AC,AB)=\gcd(AB,CF)=\gcd(CE,CF) $
3. $EB=EF$ and $EF$ is a side of a small square, while $EC$ is its diagonal, and a diagonal is longer than the side.

Comment: I hope that your answer is based on implication that $AE$ is passing through the angle bisector of angle $CAB$. But, how to know that from what is given. Also have a further issue:  it is difficult to fathom that the end $E$ of angle bisector $AE$ will also coincide with the construction $EC$, which is formed by taling perpendicular from $F$.

Comment: @jiten: Use the Hypotenuse-Leg congruence pattern.

Comment: @Blue Please elaborate as am unable to understand. Still unable after your edit. Particularly, how the construction $AE$ gels with $EC$. Thanks, but the second point of my doubt as raised in my very first comment is still not clear.

Comment: @jiten: $\overline{AE}\cong\overline{AE}$ (reflexivity), and $\overline{AB}\cong\overline{AF}$ (by assumption). Thus, $\triangle AEB$ and $\triangle AEF$ have congruent hypotenuses and congruent legs. By "Hypotenuse-Leg" (SSA works, when the "A" is a right angle), the triangles are congruent.

Comment: @jiten: $E$ is simply the point where the perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$ at $B$ meets the perpendicular to $\overline{AC}$ at $F$. Again, by Hypotenuse-Leg, $\triangle AEB \cong \triangle AEF$. Thus, $\angle EAB\cong\angle EAF$, making $\overline{AE}$ an angle bisector ... which is somewhat irrelevant, since the triangle congruence already implies the important fact: $\overline{EB}\cong\overline{EF}$.

Comment: @Blue and CiaPan - Please vet it:  It is all a special property of Pythagorean theorem that the SSA (with angle A being the half angle of angle $CAB$, with implied angle bisection being done) is used to derive the third side ($EB=EF$) also equal, as well to coincide $E$ of $AE$ with $EC$.

Comment: @jiten See: $AF=AB$ implies $EF \overset{\text{Pyth. in }\triangle AFE}= \sqrt{AE^2-AF^2} = \sqrt{AE^2-AB^2} \overset{\text{Pyth. in }\triangle ABE} = EB$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it is special consequence of the Pythagorean theorem that need not assume any implied angle division (of $CAB$). In fact, the angle $CAB$ bisection follows from proving SSS congruence.

Comment: Please vet: in fact AAA/SSS congruence could also be used as the Pythagorean theorem is used. There is no explicit need to use SSA congruence, and is a matter of choice.

Comment: @jiten Angles are not given, except a right angle in each triangle, so you can't use any AA rule. Additionally, AAA proves similarity only, but not congruency (doesn't establish scale=1). The SSA rule doesn't work for A acute; luckily we have a right angle here, but in general I prefer SSS. That's why I involved Pythagoras. Anyway, we needed $EF=EB$, not the triangles' congruency. Congruency is a side result here; using similarity as a step in a proof, and then deducing congruency from sides' equality makes the proof unnecessary longer.

Comment: @ CiaPen Thanks a lot for your kindest help.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle $ABF$ is isosceles on the basis $BF$ by construction; therefore the angles $\widehat{AFB}$ and $\widehat{ABF}$ are equal.

The angles $\widehat{ABE}$ and $\widehat{AFE}$ are right by construction. Thus $\widehat{EFB}$ and $\widehat{EBF}$ are equal because complementary to equal angles. Hence $EFB$ is an isosceles triangle on the basis $BF$; therefore $EF=EB$.

Your second question stems from the fact that, if $a>b$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$ (the very fact on which the Euclidean algorithm is based).

Finally, $EC>EF$ because the diagonal in a square is greater than the side; and we proved $EF=EB$, so $EC>EB$.